# Used Hard Drive cannot be assigned a letter

Tags: macos, hard-drive, windows-10, disk-management

I have installed an internal hard drive into my PC to try to look at the files in it. This drive was previously installed in a faulty MacBook, and I needed some valuable files. When I installed the hard drive, I went into Disk Management, and the hard drive was recognised, but I couldn't edit the drive letter. I cannot do anything to it, and there is data inside that I need so cannot reformat it.

I've tried Linux Reader and the main partition doesn't have a file system, so I get an error as seen in the pictures.

Properties of the main partition:

[image: Properties of the main partition]

Error message that shows when I try to open it:

[image: Error message that shows when I try to open it]

Comment: You could look at [this link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-ways-read-mac-formatted-drive-windows/): it looks as though `HFSExplorer` will solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Paragon HFS+ for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/). Once installed, Paragon HFS+ for Windows provides a high-speed read and write access to Mac-formatted partitions just as if it is a native Windows driver

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sth like Linux Reader. The drive you inserted is with other filesystem than the Windows can accept. Use Linux from CD/DVD or USB drive to read the data or use Linux Reader.

[Link](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/)

Comment: When I try to access the drive, it comes up with Can't open disk [diskname]. Check the disk and try again

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? More information needed! What are you trying to click?

Comment: Either when I try to open the "TOSHIBA" Physical Drive or when I try to open the "Volume 1(Macintosh HD, Mac OS X)", it comes up with the error. I have updated the post so it provides pictures of the error and the properties of the "Volume 1".

Comment: You need to open partition, not the whole drive. Try other objects in this window.

Comment: The partition that I referenced contains 464.96 Gb of data, pretty much the whole drive. The other objects worked fine.